# UICollectionView Xamarin.iOS, Custom cell with button

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I have read many tutorial out there for UICollectionView for both iOS and Xamarin.iOS
Everybody has shown same sample tutorial with one image inside UICollectionViewCell

**Desired output**

UICollectionViewCell with custom design
[image: GridView]

**What I have done**

This is what I have achieved so far.. please ignore the bad design :P
[image: UICollectionView in Xamarin.iOS]

**Problem**

When I Click on Book button, it triggers the event multiple times. The weird thing is that its not consistent, sometimes it will trigger only once some time twice or some time three times or whatever...

**Code Snippet**

```
List<MeetingRoom> data = new List<MeetingRoom>();

async public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    data = await DashboardServices.getMeetingRooms(DateTime.Now);
    MeetingRoomCollection.WeakDataSource = this;
}

public nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
{
    var count = data.Count;
    return count;
}

public UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = (MeetingRoomCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("cell", indexPath);

    cell.RoomName.Text = data[indexPath.Row].Room_Name;
    cell.Status.Text = data[indexPath.Row].Availability;
    cell.BookButton.Tag = indexPath.Row;
    cell.BookButton.TouchUpInside += Cell_BookButton_TouchUpInside;

    return cell;
}

void Cell_BookButton_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = sender as UIButton;

    Debug.WriteLine("index : {0}, status : {1}", (int)x.Tag, data[(int)x.Tag].Availability);
    this.PerformSegue("segue_bookRoom", this);
}
```

Please suggest what needs to be done to fix this issue, any reference to available tutorial would be appreciated. It will be great if Xamarin.iOS hint is there..

Comment: Try to unsubscribe from the event first then subscribe to prevent multiple triggers.
`cell.BookButton.TouchUpInside -= Cell_BookButton_TouchUpInside;cell.BookButton.TouchUpInside += Cell_BookButton_TouchUpInside;`

Tell me if it works for yout to post as answer, I don't have Mac Right now to test it.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work.. :)

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to solve this issue is to unsubscribe from event before subscribing it, this way it will prevent multiple calls especially if this item is recycled in list.

```
cell.BookButton.TouchUpInside -= Cell_BookButton_TouchUpInside;
cell.BookButton.TouchUpInside += Cell_BookButton_TouchUpInside;
```